# Adding Multiple Webhooks /// JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about adding 2 more webhooks to this function?

There do not need to be completed at the same time but they can be.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/3248796/ooof4md/',
    data: sendData,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data)
```

Here is the full code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/3248796/ooof4md/',
    data: sendData,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    $('.js-message').removeClass('message--success').removeClass('message--error');
    $(document).find('.js-message p').remove();
    if (data.status == 'success') {
        $('.js-message').addClass('message--success').append('<p>You have successfully submitted your application!</p>');

        if( income === 'o5k' ){
            url = '/application-2/book-call-1/';
        }else{
            url = '/application-2/book-call/';
        }
        window.location.href = url;
    } else {
    $('.js-message').addClass('message--error').append('<p>There was an error. Please try again!</p>');
    }
    $('.js-message').slideDown();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.js-message').slideUp();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Move the `done` callback into a function and call that from inside `done`.  Then just duplicate the call with different Urls.